# np.lexsort switch between ascending and descending order

Tags: python, numpy, sorting

I have an numpy array with `x` columns and want to sort by multiple columns (some of which may be of type `np.str_`. I know that I can do this using `np.lexsort`.

Is there a way to specify if ascending / descending order for each sorting column?

Example: I know that I can sort via multiple columns as follows:
(**EDITED TO INDICATE STRING COLUMNS!**

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([list("aaabbb"),[1,2,3,1,4,3],[1,2,3,4,6,6]]).T # Define arr
idx = np.lexsort([arr[:,1], arr[:,2]]) # sort by column 2 and then by column 1 (i.e. reversed order)
arr = arr[idx]
```

I also understand that I can sort in descending order as follows:

```
arr = arr[idx[::-1]]
```

This results in first sort column (column 2) to be descending and the subsequent columns in ascending order.

But how do I specify that I want first sort (column 2) in descending order and subsequent sort (column 1) descending order so that I get the following.

**desired OUTPUT**:

```
array([['b', 4, 6],
       ['b', 3, 6],
       ['b', 1, 4],
       ['a', 3, 3],
       ['a', 2, 2],
       ['a', 1, 1]]
```

So basically for my example I am looking something equivalent to:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=list("abc"))
df.sort_values(by=["c","b"], ascending=[False, False])
```

In general I want to be able to specifcy (i) columns to be sorted and (ii) sorting order per column (ascending/descending).

Comment: What's your desired output

Comment: Edited to make desired output more visible

Comment: Answered! Cool question.

Answer (score 5):

Try using the minus sign for reversing, it basically sorts by the negative of each value, which actually works:

```
idx = np.lexsort([arr[:,1], -arr[:,2]])
```

Output:

```
array([[2, 3, 6],
       [2, 4, 6],
       [2, 1, 4],
       [1, 3, 3],
       [1, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 1]])
```

If there would be strings, try:

```
idx = np.lexsort([arr[:,1], arr[:,2]])
arr = arr[idx]
arr[:, 0] = arr[:, 0][::-1]
```

Output:

```
array([['2', '1', '1'],
       ['2', '2', '2'],
       ['2', '3', '3'],
       ['1', '1', '4'],
       ['1', '3', '6'],
       ['1', '4', '6']], 
      dtype='<U11')
```

**Edit:**

With the new edit:

```
arr = arr[::-1]
```

Would work:

```
array([['b', '4', '6'],
       ['b', '3', '6'],
       ['b', '1', '4'],
       ['a', '3', '3'],
       ['a', '2', '2'],
       ['a', '1', '1']], 
      dtype='<U1')
```

Comment: Thanks. But this will not work for `np.str_` case because I cannot mutiply by -1. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @FredMaster I don't quite understand what you mean by that, you should try it first, it probably would work

Comment: If one of the columns is of type string it will not work. E.g. if you switch to `arr = np.array([list("aaabbb"),[1,2,3,1,4,3],[1,2,3,4,6,6]]).T` your solution will not work.

Comment: @FredMaster Check out my second code with slicing, that one works

Comment: Thanks. I edited my post to make a bit clearer want I want. I played around with your solution but this is not exactly what I want. Or maybe I am interpreting your solution the wrong way.

Comment: @FredMaster Edited my answer should work now Check my **Edit:** section

Comment: @FredMaster If it still doesn't work, maybe around 10 hours from now I will be back, bye

Comment: Thanks for your responses. Unfortunately, this still does not solve my problem. Please note that my `arr` is just a toy example. This should work for other arrays as specified in the first line of my example as well.